# ehcache restful service methods override/extend

Tags: ehcache, spring-cache

my question may be vague to ask. I am trying to use ehcache restful service methods such as get or put. I am not sure how this works under hood, is there any way I can override these methods? I mean, get always looks up in cache, but I want to look up in database if not found in cache. I can implement this behavior by writing my own rest service methods, but is there anyway to use ehcache built-in rest functionality by overriding their methods or extend their methods to look up in database if not found in cache. Appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: are you trying to use Ehcache to cache rest calls? or are you trying to use http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/modules/cache-server.html ?

Comment: yes, I wanted to use cache-server, but it provides basic operations, but I want to extend the lookup operations, like, looking up in multiple caches using single get call?